# Apply movement for a specific interval

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a character in unity, I want to move it to the right for 3 seconds, and then move it to the left for 3 seconds, and again to the right and so on... like a loop movement.

How can I do that? Is it possible to reset the time of Time.time?

```
void Update () {

        starttime = Time.time; 

        if (starttime < 3)
        {
            rigidbody.AddForce(rigidbody.transform.TransformDirection((new Vector3(0, 0, 1)) * 5));
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can not reset Time.time but you can just do something like this:

```
private float walkTime = 3f; // seconds to walk in each direction
private float direction = 1f; // right or left

void Start() {
    starttime = Time.time;
}

void Update () {
    rigidbody.AddForce(rigidbody.transform.TransformDirection((new Vector3(direction, 0, 0)) * 5));
    if (starttime + walkTime <= Time.time) {
        direction *= -1;
        starttime=Time.time;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a coroutine that `yield return new WaitForSeconds(3)`, then calls a callback you provided, which will apply new forces.